# FileOutputStream generated but can't be downloaded

Tags: java

I have a generated an Excel file using this code:

```
try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\new1.xls"));
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();
   System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
}
```

So how can I download it after this file is written?

**UPDATE1:**

I'm not using servlet. I'm using struts2, and this class, to generate my Excel file with poi.jar .

```
public class ExportToExcel{

    public void execToexcel() {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

        Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
        data.put("1", new Object[] {"Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"});
        ...
        }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = 
                    new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\new1.xls"));
            workbook.write(out);
            DownloadManager.downloadFile("out");
            //out.flush();
            // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("new1.xls"); 
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: download? from where to where?

Comment: And the problem is? Also: open your I/O resource in front of a try block and close it in finally; or if you use Java 7, use a try-with-resource statements.

Comment: thanks for reply, my file is generated,but i want this file to be open in browser.so any ideas

Comment: Please, make efforts. To get precise answer, you really need to add some context. As I understand, you should have a look to **ServletResponse.getOutputStream()**, with a correct content type. That a really common need, google those words to get answers

Comment: see update1 for more infos

Comment: i updated my question here :http://www.liferay.com/fr/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/25486231

Answer (score 0):

I suppose to download this file from web page, maybe you can use this method.

```
public void donwloadFile(){

    try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream b= // put here the ByteArray of the content of your file
        if(b!=null){
            FacesContext facesContext=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse)facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/xls");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\""nameFile.xls\"");

            BufferedOutputStream output=null;
            output=new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

            output.write(b.toByteArray());
            output.close();

            // Inform JSF to not take the response in hands.
            facesContext.responseComplete();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a JSF-only solution.

Comment: I believe that you can use `response.setContentType(mimeType);  
              
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();  
            os.write(b);  
            os.flush();`

Comment: i'm using serveResource methode but i have no result,i have a white blank page.